# Which database to use?

Tags: database, sqlite, cross-platform

I have the requirements to write a cross platform (win/linux) desktop applications. What database would I use that is similar to sqlite? (minimal to no setup required)

Comment: Sqlite is the simplest, but im looking for an alternative

Comment: Please let us know what you don't like about sqlite.

Comment: I love using sqlite in my projects, its just that I'm looking for an alternative database that has similar capabilities in terms of being cross platform, minimal configuration (most valued by me), easily deployable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good "cross platform" (i.e. Java) databases are

- [Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/)
- [HSQLDB](http://www.hsqldb.org/)
- [H2](http://h2database.com/html/main.html)

They can all be installed very quickly and support in-memory or server modes. But probably you'll be happy with SQLite, too...?

Comment: H2 looks like what best suits my requirements

Comment: I experience it to be a very active project with lots of traction in the news group. It's probably a good choice for the future.